# Able to open TCP port but not listening

Tags: windows, tcp, port, telnet, portqry

Using Add rule in windows firewall, I was able to open TCP port 15537. When i am trying to executing command `netstat -ano` on terminal windows, this port is not listed. I tried to execute telnet command on terminal window (e.g. telnet IP port) but getting

> Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 15537: Connect failed

Then I downloaded PortQry application and execute it from different machine, this machine is also in the same network, the result I received was

> "Not Listening".

I already spent more than 2 days and asked internal group but could not find solution.

Note: both machines are having Windows 10 OS.

Comment: There has to be some server application running on that port. Just opening the firewall won't magically cause something to start.

Comment: i think, windows 10 is not having telnet server, it is depreciated

Comment: @User3001812: There's no need for a Telnet server here, and yes it is no longer supported, but the Telnet-Client still is supported.

Answer (score 3):

No solution is needed as no problem is indicated in the question. You have opened a TCP port successfully. You have not made any attempt to cause anything to listen to that TCP port.

It's not clear what results you expected, but you got the results that you should have expected. Nothing is wrong. The port is open because you opened it. Nothing is listening on that port because you didn't set anything to listen on that port.

Answer (score 0):

To view all open ports from a firewall perspective:

```
netsh firewall show portopening
```

You can then correlate that output with:

```
netstat -ano
```

to confirm if there are indeed services on said ports.

Answer (score -1):

Use nmap instead of netstat for detecting opening port

nmap -p your_port_number your_local_ip

Run service on that port

For eg- In my case,in order to open port,I use 
"service ssh start"  or "service apache2 start "and it's open port 22 and 80 for connection respectively in my linux machine.

On using nmap in my lan network both ports opened.
Hope it help

Answer (score -1):

There may be some forwarding rules? Since the purpose of access is not on the local machine, the netstat command cannot see the port on listening, but it can see the next action based on this port, usually to do some forwarding

I am not very familiar with windows firewall configuration, but I know that if there is a forwarding rule in linux, like

-p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j {other forwading chain}

we can not see 8080 listening on this host (netstat -tunpl), but telnet host:8080 may see connected